# Lipstick plant dry stems and fallen leafs

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

I bought a healthy lipstick plant about 3 months ago but everyday I see fallen leaves or dried stems or both.

I made sure I water when the top 2 inch if soil is dry and to mist it every now and then.

Here is how it looked then:

[image]

and here is how it looks now:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are waiting till the top two inches of soil are dry before watering, you're not watering enough. Whilst water should be reduced in winter, normal watering should be done in the growing season, spring and summer, which means watering thoroughly when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, and allowing excess water to flow away freely. As yours is in a  pot with an integral tray, you'll need to tip the whole pot sideways 30 minutes after watering to remove any excess still sitting there.

The other thing is lighting - you don't say what kind of light it gets, but it should be bright daylight with no direct sunlight. These plants naturally grow in humid conditions, so depending on the humidity in the room, you probably need to mist daily rather than occasionally. Further info [Aeschynanthus 'Mona Lisa'
lipstick plant](https://www.rhsplants.co.uk/plants/_/aeschynanthus-mona-lisa/classid.2000034425/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im heartbroken. do you think it can be saved?

Comment: For sunlight i sometime leave it under a north facing window. but its probably every other day

Comment: It might recover, but find a suitable spot indoors for it rather than moving it around all the time. Houseplants really prefer to settle into a suitable spot...